# Acknowledgement didn't work..Teltonika FM5300

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, gps

Here is a sample of my code. It doesn't work. I sent acknowledgement in the right form {0x01} but the device always returns only IMEI. Could someone solve this problem?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener list = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2065));
        TcpClient client;

        Console.WriteLine("Listening... \n");

        list.Start(1);
        list.Server.NoDelay = true;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...\n");
            client = list.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected ");
            byte[] imei = new byte[8192];

            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            if (ns.CanRead)
            {
                ns.Read(imei, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(imei, 0, imei.Length));
            byte[] ack = new byte[1] {0x01};
            if (ns.CanWrite)
            {
                ns.Write(ack, 0, ack.Length);
            }
            client.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is it supposed to send back? You keep sending the same thing over and over, why do you expect different results?

Comment: ok i expalin you 1. GPS sent only IMEI, 2. Server must sent acknowledgement 01 (accept recieving from gps) or 00 not. 3. GPS send data to server @Ron Beyer

Comment: do you have idea how to solve this problem? :)

Comment: but if I send 01 as HEX via Hercules (terminal).....teltonika working great...i dont know where is prolem in my code. @Ron Beyer

Comment: Like Ron said, you keep sending the same thing over and over. After you receive IMEI, your code sends correct response **and disconnects**. So next connection starts from beginning, with IMEI... The data from device comes over the same connection, so... why disconnect? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like Ron said, you keep sending the same thing over and over. After you receive IMEI, your code sends correct response **and disconnects**. So next connection starts from beginning, with IMEI... The data from device comes over the same connection, so... why disconnect? ;)
                    – mlask